# Nginx & Passenger not showing my Ruby on Rails app Landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to deploy `Ruby on Rails` app with `Passenger` and `Nginx` server on DigitalCloud droplet.

I have installed successfully Nginx and Passenger on my Ubuntu environment. Also i cloned my rails app on `/var/www/my_app` but I think nginx config file is not properly set. I don't know what is problem, because in several tutorials they have same configuration and they are telling everything is good.

So what I see is this:
[image: Rails error message]

You can see it is standard rails error page from `my_app/public` folder.

I can't figure out why in all these tutorials they make root folder `/public`, because there is only located error pages and my favicon. I would like it to display index page from my `static page controller` as it is defined in app `routes` file as root url.

Here is my `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  My_App;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /var/www/my_app/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

I would need it to display index page called `home.html.erb` in `/var/www/my_app/views/static_pages` through controller called `static_pages`. It would be logical to somehow provide `Nginx` with info that is in rails `routes` file because there is all it needs to know, but I haven't seen anyone do that. Maybe you could tell what is solution? All tutorials say direct it to public folder, but it doesn't work.

Thanks Anyways.

Comment: what? i think you are mixing up some things here...

Comment: I had to install database and it worked :D I should read more about things I use.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. I needed to install database because it can't run without one. That is strange, because i thought i need one only if my app will need it for storing something. My fault :D

This tutorial had it all! http://alexbachuk.com/launch-rails-4-application-with-passenger-and-nginx/ Hope it can help others too.

Anyway, solution found.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on finding a solution. You can select it as the answer once the system allows it. It's not a good idea to ask a question in an answer though. Answers are for answers, not more questions. Stack Overflow isn't a bulletin-board where there is a stream of questions and answers. Instead consider it a cookbook or reference book. If you have additional questions you need to create an additional question and ask there, or should have asked in your original question. Remember though, on Stack Overflow we allow one, or two closely related, questions per page.

Comment: Never in my life I thought there can be such disciplined community online! I love it :)) and I will remove additional question. Thanks.

Comment: It's quite well thought-out. Check out [metaso] to see how the user-base decides things.